# What is $\beta$ in this equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, terminology

I have a book called "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, corrected and enlarged edition, English translation. It said that, in section 8.37: $$\psi\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)-\psi\left(\frac x2\right)=2\beta(x)$$Where $\psi$ is defined as the digamma function in this book. I am writing a paper and one of my formulas would be simplified if I replaced the LHS with the RHS, but I needed to find the name of this function first. I looked at the list of functions, wondering what's $\beta$, and all it said was "incomplete beta functions" along with $\text{B}_x(p,q)$. The second one is just the incomplete Beta function, but I don't know what $\beta(x)$ would be. It might've been a specific function from $\text{B}_x(p,q)$ but I didn't get anywhere when putting random values for $p$ and $q$.

It gave some other relations for $\beta$, and it did look like some beta function, but I wasn't able to find its name.

PS: Not related, but the authors of this book decided to denote the Euler-Mascheroni constant as $C$, even though almost everyone uses $\gamma$. The authors knew about that notation but they said that symbol is used for $e^C$. The only symbol I am aware of for $e^C$ is $\gamma'$ and not $\gamma$.

Edit: Thanks to @Moo's help, it seems that there is no name for $\beta$ and I would have to define it in the paper.

Comment: Doesn't it define $\beta(x)$ in Section $8.37$?

Comment: It also provides various ways to define it from integral, series, and functional relations.

Comment: @Moo Okay, thanks for the help. But if I were to use this function in a paper, what would I call it (so I don't have to re-write that definition)?

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect that it's now about terminology. People shouldn't have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @KamalSaleh: If you look at the "Index of Special Functions" in the book, you see that it is one of a handful of special functions that does not have a name. So, you may have to define an example of the formula's definition, and then point to the reference for the other ones.